# Retrive all rows from last month (Laravel + Eloquent)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to get all records that belongs to last month, so far I managed to get all from last month but to date today, I'm not sure how I can get only for last month

```
$revenueMonth = Callback::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->startOfMonth()->subMonth())->sum('payment');
```

Comment: are you getting list of records of previous month with this query?

Comment: I'm getting all records from start last month to todays date, so example: 2017-08-01 -> 2017-09-07 instead of 2017-08-01 -> 2017-08-31

Comment: so what you want let me know so that I can help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

More clear solution for your problem:

```
$revenueMonth = Callback::whereMonth(
    'created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month
);
```

Comment: Just want to point out that this will take the last month integer and return records from all years matching that month. Let's say it's November, Carbon would return "10". So, this query would match on created_at = '2018-10-01 12:23:34' AND it would also match on created_at = '2015-10-10 13:24:35'... not _just_ the last month. The SQL it returns is basically where month(created_at) = 10.

Answer (score 10):

Try this solutions:

```
$revenueMonth = Callback::where(
    'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString()
);
```

You get all Callback for last 30 days.

```
$revenueMonth = Callback::where(
    'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->firstOfMonth()->toDateTimeString()
);
```

Get  for current month.

```
$revenueMonth = Callback::where(
    'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth()->toDateString()
);
```

Get for start last month.

**UPDATED**

```
$revenueMonth = Callback::where(
    'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->toDateTimeString()
);
```

This is what are you looking for :)

Hope it will help you:)

Comment: I'm not looking for the last 30 days for rather for the last month, so example: 2017-08-01 -> 2017-08-31 instead of 2017-08-24 -> 2017-09-7 :)

Comment: $revenueMonth = Callback::where(
    'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth()->toDateString()
);

That returns:
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-08-07 09:46:43
2017-09-02 09:46:43

And I'm only looking for
2017-08-07 09:46:43

Comment: Hmm still not working as I want :P. It returns 2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-02 09:46:43

And I'm looking for it to return the record of: 2017-08-07 09:46:43

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATED**
eloquent version of the your answer

```
$fromDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->toDateString();
$tillDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->toDateString();

$revenueLastMonth = Callback::whereBetween('created_at',[$fromDate,$tillDate])->get();
```

Comment: $revenueMonth = Callback::where(
   'created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()
->startOfMonth()->subMonth(1)->toDateTimeString()); That returns: 2017-09-07 09:46:43 2017-09-07 09:46:43 2017-09-07 09:46:43 2017-08-07 09:46:43 2017-09-02 09:46:43 And I'm only looking for 2017-08-07 09:46:43

Comment: I have edited my answer check it and if still doesn't work then let me know :)

Comment: It still returns everything from 2017-08-07 09:46:43 to 2017-09-07 09:46:43, I have added an answer myself, but I think it could be made in a different way, just don't know how :)

Comment: yeah I have edited your and my answer try the eloquent way as suggested in docs

Answer (score 4):

None of the answers get's me to where I'm looking to go :(.

I have a solution but I think it's ugly and hoped it could be made more clean

```
$fromDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->toDateString();
$tillDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->toDateString();

$revenueLastMonth = Callback::whereBetween(DB::raw('date(created_at)'), [$fromDate, $tillDate])->get();
```

This will give my the result I'm looking for, here is my records:

```
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-07 09:46:43
2017-09-02 09:46:43
2017-08-07 09:46:43
```

And I want it to return ONLY what records is made in August 2017 (2017-08-07 09:46:43)