# Eloquent / DB get months between two dates

Tags: sql, laravel, date

I'm using Laravel 5.4.

I have a Booking model which contains a `start_date` and an `end_date`. The user chooses a month from a dropdown list.

I would like `Eloquent` to return all records where the month is between the boundaries of the `start_date` and `end_date`.

e.g Show all Bookings that are in September (even if the booking started before (or during September) AND (boolean) ends in September or later.

Any suggestion would be welcome. Happy for this to be a raw SQL statement if needs be.

Comment: It will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098040/7155723

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096498/7155723

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I'll have a look - cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me:

```
$start = Carbon::now()->addMonth(-1);
$end = Carbon::now()->addMonth();

$bookings = Booking::whereRaw('MONTH(created_at) > :0 AND MONTH(created_at) < :1',[
    $start->month, $end->month
])
->orWhereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = :3 AND DAYOFMONTH(created_at) >= :4', [ 
    $start->month, $start->day
])
->orWhereRaw('MONTH(created_at) = :5 AND DAYOFMONTH(created_at) <= :6', [
    $end->month, $end->day
])
->get();
```

If you want to exclude the start and end dates you can replace `>=` with `>` and `<=` with `<`.

And ofcourse, you have to change the `$start` and `$end` dates. They should be `Carbon\Carbon` objects.

Answer (score 0):

First, on client side or server side parse the users picked month to something like:

```
$selected = "2017-09";
```

Then:

```
Booking::where([
    ['start_time','>', $selected],
    ['end_time','<', $selected]
])->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'll play with this later!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
$bookings = DB::table('bookings')
            ->whereMonth('start_date', '<', $date->month)->whereMonth('end_date', '>=', $date->month)
            ->orWhere(function($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereMonth('start_date', $date->month);
            })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty straightforward.

I'm not sure what format the "month" is in but you should use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to get your `DateTime` object.  Feel free to use `Carbon` if you are familiar.  I find for simple things like this, it's adding unnecessary complexity.

Then query using it.

```
Booking::whereBetween($dateTime->format('Y-m-00'), [DB::raw('start_date'), DB::raw('end_date')])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding some explain :

```
Booking::whereRaw("(start_date, end_date) overlaps (date '2021-06-01', date '2021-06-30')")->get();
```

Comment: please explain your answer or share some link to documentation

Comment: "Adding some explain :" Please do so. I currently do not see any explanation in your post.